# How to properly access and concatenate data in vue-good-table

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-good-table

May I know how to properly access and concatenate my data in vue-good-table? Data is not appearing in the table.

Here's my code:

```
<vue-good-table
   :columns="columns"
   :rows="bigDataInformationList"
>

  <template v-slot:rows="data">
    <td>{{data.row.dataLocationSet.dataLocCity}}</td>
    <td>{{data.row.dataProfileSet.dataProfileLastName}}</td>
    <td>{{data.row.dataServicesSet[0].dataService1 ? "Yes" : "No"}}</td>
  </template>
</vue-good-table>

columns: [
{
label: 'Data City Located',
field: 'dataLocCity', -->not appearing in the table :(
},
{
label: 'Data Profile 01',
field: 'dataProfileLastName', -->not appearing in the table :(
},
{
label: 'Data Service 01',
field: 'dataService1', -->not appearing in the table :(
},
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here :** data.row.dataServicesSet[0].dataService1 ? "Yes" : "No"

you should use a function to hold the logic and to return the param that you want

```
getDataService: function (rowObj) {
  if (rowObj.dataServicesSet[0].dataService1) {
    return 'yes'
  } else {
    return 'no
  }
}
```

and use it like this : 
this.getDataService()